# How do I reuse HTML code for different pages just like every popular website in existence?

Tags: html

On almost every website, they have various pages, each having the same HTML code. I strongly doubt that the creators of the websites edit the HTML code of each page, especially when users can make their own pages (like redditors making their own subreddits). These two pages from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_machine are different pages but they have very similar html code

And I don't even need to have users create their own pages, I just need to have multiple pages that reuse html code. https://www.apple.com/mac/ https://www.apple.com/ipad/ are clearly different pages that have different html code, but I don't think the developers would copy and paste HTML code, change it, then change the code of the headers in each page to include the new page when they have a new product.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/ are different pages that use the same html code. What do they use? Should I learn bootstrap? I've seen websites do this way before bootstrap was made, though. What's something like this called? Do they even write in HTML or do they write in something that compiles into HTML? How am I supposed to do this very simple task that every webdev knows how to do yet I am unable to find any information on it?

I've tried searching for "Reusing HTML code" but I found nothing that answers my question. All I've seen are special cases

I'm hoping with this, I'll be able to have a website that can have multiple pages that use the same basic HTML code. If I wanted a new tab, I won't have to edit the HTML code of each page.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is achieved by HTML templates and server-side scripting. The server script injects data in your HTML template, thus reusing one template for any number of pages. A template may consist of multiple parts that can be combined to achieve similarly looking yet different pages. It is called dynamic HTML.

Here is a very basic tutorial on how it works: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

To create a modern website you need to use a dozen different technologies together. Here is an infographic to give get idea: https://codeburst.io/the-2018-web-developer-roadmap-826b1b806e8d

Answer (score 0):

They are many ways to do it!
If you are using asp.net you can use master page.
For more info : [Master page demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-master-page-in-asp-net/)

or else you can use php "include" statement. Suppose you created one page as header.php(header.html) and other one as footer.php(footer.html), then you just have to include those pages.
eg

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<html>your web page</html>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this question is so extremely general it's hard to answer without knowing what your goal is.  I highly doubt there are any web developers that develop a website from scratch anymore.  Most use a content management system (CMS) which uses server side scripting to serve HTML pieces to form a website. For example header, footer, content-body I don't mean the HTML tags header and footer, although they will be part of the pieces the CMS serves.  The most popular content management system is Wordpress, which is built in php.  The pages don't even need to be specifically designated, they can be a list of blog posts, a picture gallery ...etc . There are many different CMS packages that serve different purposes and depend on your requirements.  Wordpress is in my opinion the simplest with the lowest learning curve and is quite powerful, especially with all of the templates and plugins available.  Wordpress itself is free and there are many free templates to start from.  However, there are paid templates and plugins that offer additional features.  The only thing that you need is php support and a hosting site.

All you need to know can be found here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress

Other content management systems include Joomla, Drupal, Magento, PrestaShop, TYPO3.  Each have their advantages and disadvantages, as well as varying support for plugins and templates.  Some are designed to support eCommerce sites, such as PrestaShop and TYPO3 but most CMS libraries provide support for eCommerce through plugins and templates.

Bootstrap is a framework, which is a little different from a CMS, but it offers a similar functionality.  It serves different pieces or containers you design to form a website or page.

I recommend starting with Wordpress and if you have more specialized needs, check out the other options.  I don't recommend you start writing php code to serve pages unless you are a very experienced php coder and even in that case why would you want to if there are so many free open source tools that have already done this for you.